# Hive -> Kafka: Insert into hive kafka integration external table failed

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hive, integration

```
#Exception I got:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ParquetHiveRecord cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaWritable

    #create non-native external hive table    
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weatherHive(lng DOUBLE, lat DOUBLE, avg_tmpr_f DOUBLE, avg_tmpr_c DOUBLE, wthr_date STRING) PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT) TBLPROPERTIES ('kafka.topic' = 'weatherHive', 'kafka.bootstrap.servers'='sandbox-hdp:6667', "kafka.serde.class"="org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe" );
    #insert test data 
    INSERT INTO TABLE weatherHive VALUES (-111,22,80,23,'2016-10-01',2020, 10 ,1 );
```

Then I got the exception, what should I do, is there anything I need to do with the handler jar ? 
which I loaded into hive:

```
add add jar hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/sandbox/jars/kafka-handler-3.1.2000.7.0.3.0-79.jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaSerDe". Check out [this answer](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-kafka-integration-giving-error-class-not-found/td-p/269580).